# PHP library for Xliff

Tags: php, xml, xliff

Is there any library that gets as input an xliff segment and "serializes" it to be displayed in the browser ?

Answer (score 1):

Xliff implementation for PHP.

http://code.google.com/p/goatherd-php-library/wiki/Xliff

Answer (score 1):

So, my little reasearch of this topic. Can be interpreted as answer as well.

Scope: PHP and its implementations.

Went to link above -> http://code.google.com/p/goatherd-php-library/wiki/Xliff , latest update: May 8, 2011

Then googled (keyword: "php xliff") for this link: https://github.com/oyagev/PHP-XLIFF - latest update: Dec 24, 2012

Then went (back?) to Wikipedia for more listings of such tools: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XLIFF

Then found this site: http://phptrends.com/dig_in/xliff

then re-cosidered Zend Framework: https://www.google.lv/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=php+xliff+zend / http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.translate.adapter.html

And finally started to decide, how to migrate half-translated data from database and localization-contained php files. :)

So, my choice was the project from Github.